# quantifiers in logically equivalent implications

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm really confused as to why:
∃x∈D (p(x)⇒E) is logically equivalent to (∀x∈D p(x))⇒E
p(x) is a generic predicate based on x and E is a predicate that is unrelated to x.
∀x∈D (p(x)⇒E) is also logically equivalent to (∃x∈D p(x))⇒E
Can someone please help?

Comment: I would start by writing $p(x) \implies E$ as $\lnot p(x) \lor E$.  If there exists $x$ that makes this true,  the choice of $x$ has no effect on the truth or falsity of $E$

Answer (score 0):

The sentence "$\exists x \in D(P(x) \implies E)$" says "There is some object such that *if* that object has property $P$, then $E$ is true." Now, suppose some $x$ doesn't have $P$. Then the statement "$P(x) \implies E$" is **vacuously** true (recall that "if A then B" is considered true if A is false). If, on the other hand, *every* $x$ has $P$, then the statement "$\exists x \in D(P(x) \implies E)$ can only be true if $E$ is, because the existential quantifier has to "pick" an $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true. So in other words, the sentence is true in exactly the following two situations: either (a) some $x$ doesn't have property $P$, or (b) every $x$ has property $P$ and $E$ is true.

The sentence $(\forall x \in D)P(x) \implies E$ is true if either (a) $(\forall x \in D)P(x)$ is false, or (b) $(\forall x \in D)P(x)$ is true and $E$ is true also. (Remember what it means for $A \implies B$ to be true.) Translating this into English, $(\forall x \in D)P(x) \implies E$ is true in exactly the following two situations: (a) not every $x$ has property $P$ (so some $x$ does not have property $P$), or (b) every $x$ has property $P$ and $E$ is true. Notice that these are *exactly* the two situations we had for the other sentence; so the two sentences are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the equivalences you are interested in, let us first establish that for any $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi$, where $\psi$ does not contain any free variable $x$ (so this is just like your $p(x) and $E$) we have that:

Ia. $\exists x \: \varphi(x) \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi)$

To understand this, note that an existential can be seen as kind of disjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of an existential like this:

$\exists x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) \lor ...$ (I use $\approx$ since this is technically *not* a logical equivalence, but if you really want to prove the above equivalence, you'd need to go into formal semantics, and what you'll be doing there *does* follow this very idea)

So:

$\exists x \: \varphi(x) \lor \psi \approx$

$(\varphi(a) \lor \varphi(b) \lor \varphi(c) ...) \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow$ (by Association, Commutation, and since $P \Leftrightarrow P \lor P$)

$\varphi(a) \lor \psi \lor \varphi(b)  \lor \psi \lor \varphi(c) \lor \psi  ... \approx$

$\exists x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi)$

By thinking of a universal as a kind of conjunction over all objects over the domain, i.e using

$\forall x \: \varphi(x) \approx \varphi(a) \land \varphi(b) \land \varphi(c) \land ...$

you can likewise show that:

Ib. $\forall x \: \varphi(x) \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi(x) \lor \psi)$ (good exercise to do for yourself!)

OK, so now we can establish your equivalences using more more important equivalence:

II. $\varphi \rightarrow \psi \Leftrightarrow \neg \varphi \lor \psi$ (just verify this with a truth-table)

For example:

$\exists x (p(x) \rightarrow E) \Leftrightarrow$ (by II)

$\exists x (\neg p(x) \lor E) \Leftrightarrow$ (by Ia)

$\neg \exists x \: p(x) \lor E \Leftrightarrow$ (Quantifier Negation ... this is why the quantifier changes!!)

$\forall x \: \neg p(x) \lor E \Leftrightarrow$ (by Ib)

$\forall x \: (\neg p(x) \lor E) \Leftrightarrow$ (by II)

$\forall x \: (p(x) \rightarrow E)$

And again, I'll leave the other one to yourself.